# Add some jQuery after new content loaded with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to request a sub section of my page. Here is an example of what the content requested could look like:

```
<div id="NewContentAfterPageLoad">
   <form>
     ...
     <input id="clickMe" type="submit" form="aForm" value="submit">
   </form>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#clickMe').on('click', '#clickMe', function(e) {
         alert();
      });
   });
</script>
```

So this content is not present on page load.

Adding the jQuery like this doesn't work even though I'm using delegates.

**Does this mean that any jQuery has to be present on page load for the browser to read it?**

**Is there a workaround for dynamically loaded jQuery?**

Comment: how are you adding the content in page.

Comment: Is `#clickMe` the new element? The new element has to be in the second argument to `.on()`. The selector that you bind the handler to must be present on page load.

Comment: There's no `a` in the content you're requesting.

Comment: Have you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Juicy: can you please update the complete html. with selector and elements you want to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach event to element that does not change dynamically. you can also use them with `$('body')` or `$(document)`.:

```
  $('body').on('click', '#clickMe', function(e) {
     alert('test');
  });
```

Comment: There's no `a` inside `#clickMe`.

Comment: That's it, will delete this comment and give you the point in 10mins. Didn't realise I had to attach it to a static element.

Comment: It is better to use closest static element instead of using with body or document.